# How to build a continuous integration for a .net core project which includes T4 files

Tags: docker, .net-core, continuous-integration, t4

I want to build a docker container which I can use for our continuous integration. Within that, I want to build an application which needs node, .net core and within the .net core project T4 transformation. 
How can I transform T4 files which need external assemblies e.g. System.Data.DataSetExtensions in a Linux Docker container?

I tried the mono t4 engine https://github.com/mono/t4. I installed it in my docker container and I am able to do simple T4 transformation. But in our T4 files, I need assemblies. e.g.

```
<#@ Assembly Name="System.Data" #>
<#@ Import Namespace="System.Data" #>
.... some code
DataSet dsProcedures = new DataSet();       
..... more code
```

So I used `dotnet restore` to install all our dependencies within the docker container. So `System.Data.DataSetExtensions` is provided as a NuGet package.

So I tried to use command line parameters of dotnet-t4 to provide the path of the assembly. That did not help so I changed the assembly to

```
<#@ Assembly Name="/root/.nuget/packages/system.data.datasetextensions/4.5.0/lib/netstandard2.0/System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll" #>
```

At least it did not complain anymore that it can not find the assembly but now it returns the following error.

> ERROR: The type or namespace name 'DataSet' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I am using the following Dockerfile

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:sdk

RUN dotnet tool install -g dotnet-t4
ENV PATH="/root/.dotnet/tools:${PATH}"
```

Is there any way to transform T4 files with assembly dependencies in a Linux Docker container?
Would you switch to a different transformation engine?
Or is the only option to use a windows docker container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was a bug in the mono t4 library and got fixed with version 2.0.4.
For more information check the GitHub issue: https://github.com/mono/t4/issues/46